# pronunciation of the -ig suffix as [ɪç] or [ɪk], is it regional?

Tags: pronunciation

I am was pronouncing [gestrig](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/gestrig) as [ˈɡɛstʀɪç], rhyming with mich [mɪç].  My Austrian colleague did not understand me until she said, oh, you mean [ˈɡɛstʀɪk].  Wiktionary lists both the [ɪç] and [ɪk] endings for [fertig](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/fertig) but only the [ɪç] ending for gestrig.  She blamed it on her Austrian, but I'm no native speaker and certainly capable of mispronouncing words, and I certainly don't take wiktionary as gospel when faced with the word of a native speaker.  Between the [ɪç] or [ɪk] endings for words that are spelt with the -ig suffix (fertig, gestrig, häufig, gläubig, etc.), is either pronunciation more standard than the other, or is it purely a regional differenc and is either pronunciation correct?

Comment: Does she roll her *r*s? I tried to roll the *r* and pronounce the following -ig as  [ɪç] . I wasn't successful. (It felt like having a *Katarrh*.)

Comment: Standard german is [ɪç].

Comment: @Janka We don't speak German together much because we're both in England, but when I'm overhearing as she's speaking with relatives on the phone I find her quite hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is yes. The standard pronunciation for -ig ending i is regional. I have noticed that those from the north of Germany tend to pronounce it with a soft aspirate [ɪç] than with the hard [ɪk] preferred amongst Austrian, Southern Germans, and Swiss.